# How to set socks5 proxy in tweepy?

Tags: proxy, tweepy

To ssh login my vps,the codes can run successfully.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key="xxx"
consumer_secret="xxx"
access_token="xxx"
access_token_secret="xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump",weet_mode="extended",count=200)
for info in tweets:
    print(info.text)
```

Set all software related with proxy, and test socks proxy.

```
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9AC98amjSA"
youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 $url -o /tmp/downName
```

It is verified that the video on youtube can be downloaded with socks5 proxy.
All software related with proxy are in good status.
Now i want to set socks5 proxy in my local pc,only one line was changed based on the above codes.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy="127.0.0.1:1080")
```

The error info is as following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 803, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 291, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 827, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

It is no use also to add socks proxy statement as following.

```
import urllib.request
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'sock5': 'localhost:1080'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

import tweepy
consumer_key="xxx"
consumer_secret="xxx"
access_token="xxx"
access_token_secret="xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth) # or api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy="127.0.0.1:1080")
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump",weet_mode="extended",count=200)
for info in tweets:
    print(info.text)
```

How to set socks5 proxy  in tweepy?
According to  Tarun Lalwani,package installed and codes changed ,still don't work.

```
 sudo pip3   install -U requests[socks]
```

Set all related proxy software.

```
sudo netstat -anlp |grep 1080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1465/python3        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*                           1465/python3
```

Then enter into python3 console.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key="xxx"
consumer_secret="xxx"
access_token="xxx"
access_token_secret="xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080")
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump",weet_mode="extended",count=200)
```

An other error info occur.

> > > tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump",weet_mode="extended",count=200)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1716, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1431, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 445, in wrap_socket
    raise timeout('select timed out')
socket.timeout: select timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 309, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 187, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 521, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. One you need the `requests[socks]` package

```
pip install requests[socks]
```

Next you need to use the proxy in socks format

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080")
```

Comment: requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.

Comment: Try with `pip install -U requests[socks]`

Comment: Also since you are using python3, make sure to use pip3 instead of pip

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: That's a better error. That means the proxy is not working but it is connecting

Comment: What is the output to run the codes in your console?